# Show that $g(r) = (a - be^{-rt})^{+}$ is neither convex nor concave in $r$ when $b > 0$.

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

How can I show that $g(r) = (a - be^{-rt})^{+}$ is not necessarily convex nor concave in $r$ when $b > 0$?

By the way,

$$x^{+} = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } x < 0 \\[.7em] x & \text{ if } x \geq 0 \end{cases} $$

I tried plotting in Desmos to get an understanding of the function. It looks really strange at some points. You can also get a plot by entering

$$f\left(r\right)=\left\{r\ge-\frac{1}{t}\ln\left(\frac{b}{a}\right):0,\left(a-be^{-rt}\right)\right\}$$

on https://www.desmos.com/calculator.

Now, I don't know a great way to explain it. A result that the book gives is $g(r) = (ae^{-rt} - b)^{+}$ is, for $a > 0$, decreasing and convex in $r$. So I can use this result, I guess, but I don't see much relation between the two functions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are being asked to disprove something. That usually calls for finding a specific counterexample -- in this case, find a set of parameters $a$, $b$, and $t$ so that the function is not convex, and another set so that it is not concave. Unless you were specifically asked to do so, most likely there is no need to provide a theoretical explanation.

Answer (score 1):

First assume that $t>0$. Observe the following: $g=0$ for $r$ less then some number $r_0$. [ $\lim_{r \to -\infty} (a-be^{-rt})=a-b\lim_{r \to -\infty} e^{-rt}=a-b\infty=-\infty$]. (Hence $g'(r)=0$ for $r<r_0$. For $r$ sufficiently large $g'(r)=bte^{-rt} >0$. For a function which is convex or concave the derivative is monotonic. It follows that $g'$ is increasing. Hence $g'' \geq 0$. But $g''(r)=-bt^{2}e^{-rt} <0$ for $r$ sufficiently large. Hence $g$ is neither concave nor convex.

The case $t<0$ is similar.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I don't quite see why there necessarily exists an index $r_{0}$ for which $r < r_{0}$ implies $g = 0$. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @gallileo22 I am assuming that $t >0$.  $e^{-rt} \to \infty$ as $r \to -\infty$ so $a-be^{-rt} <0$ for $r$ less than some $r_0$. Hence $g(r)=0$ for $r$ less than $r_0$.

Comment: I thought $g'(r) = bte^{-rt}$, not $g'(r) = be^{-rt}$? Also, $g''(r) = -t^{2}be^{-rt}$?

Comment: @gallileo22 I have edited my answer.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the $t < 0$ case. Can you help me? Here's what I've got

Comment: There is an index $r_{0}$ so that $a - be^{-rt} < 0$ holds whenever $r \geq r_{0}$. So $g(r) = 0$ for $r \geq r_{0}$. For sufficiently small (should this be small or larger?. Actually, isn't $g'(r) < 0$ always true?) $r$, $g'(r) = bte^{-rt} < 0$ holds, which means we need to have $g'$ decreasing. So $g'' \leq 0$ but $g''(r) = -bt^{2}e^{-rt} < 0$ for $r$ small

Comment: @gallileo22 $a-be^{-rt} \to -\infty$ as $ r \to -\infty$. So $a-be^{-rt} <0$ for $r$less then some $r_0$ (which is a negative number with large value for $|r_0|$).

Comment: Ok so continuing from your comment in the case in which $t < 0$, we have $g'(r) = 0$ for $r \leq R_{0}$ and for $r$ sufficiently large, $g'(r) = bte^{-rt} > 0$.So we need to have $g'$ increasing, but $g''(r) = -bt^{2}e^{-rt} < 0$ when $r$ is large enough. Does this work? Or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: You have got it right. @gallileo22

Comment: Okay. One last question. I don't see why $a - be^{-rt}$ approaches $-\infty$ when $r \to -\infty$? Because $t$ is negative, which means the $e^{-rt}$ term will have negative exponent (since we are choosing $r$ to also be negative). So $be^{-rt}$ will become small, and $a - be^{-rt}$ will become approximately equal to $a$, right?

Comment: Woudn't $a - be^{-rt}$ approach $-\infty$ when $r\to\infty$? Not $r\to -\infty$? By the way, I am talking about the case in which $t < 0$